# Cannot find symbol getTextContent error while compiling Java code in PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, toad

I'm trying to compile a Java code into Oracle DB using PL/SQL. I've imported required libraries using loadjava command.

I am able to run my project in Eclipse without any issues.
But when I compile the Java code into Toad using Create Java Source, I'm getting below error.

```
240: cannot find symbol method getTextContent()
location: interface org.w3c.dom.Node
retVal = node.getTextContent();
```

Need to know why this is happening.
JDK 1.6 is configured in my Oracle Database.

Comment: What Java version is used inside Oracle DB?

Comment: JDK Version is 1.6